# Set Limit to seekbar's drag range

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have a list of seekbars. What I want is to set the limit of seekbar. Although I have done it by using `seekBar.setMax(anyIntValue);` but this sets the whole seekbar value. But what I want is for example user selects the first seekbar to 90% the second one should only be dragged to 10%.

This is my code:

```
holder.shelfShareSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                holder.percentTextView.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                remainingShelfShare = 100 - shelfShareSum;
                seekBar.setMax(remainingShelfShare);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                list.get(position).setSetSlider(seekBar.getProgress());
                shelfShareSum = 0;

                productShelfShareMap.put(((Products)list.get(position)).getProductID(), Integer.parseInt(holder.percentTextView.getText().toString()));
                for (HashMap.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : productShelfShareMap.entrySet()){
                    shelfShareSum += entry.getValue();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: You need to customize the seek bar in that case .

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? @ADM or can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code working fine for me.

```
seekBar1 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
seekBar2 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
```

set seekBarChangeListener on both seekBar

```
 //seekBar1
 seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

           if(seekBar2.getProgress()>0){
               seekBar2.setProgress(0);
               seekBar2.setFocusable(false);
           }
        }
    });

//seekBar2


 seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

Now add setOnTouchListener on seekBar2 for stop tracking Touch event in seekBar2

```
  seekBar2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            int firstProgress = (100 - seekBar1.getProgress()); //100 max range of seekBar
            int secondProgress = seekBar2.getProgress();
            return secondProgress >= firstProgress;
        }
    });
```

I hope migh be helpful this code.